# SQL query - table with 300 columns and 120 million records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 300 columns and more than 120 million records. I want to execute a query like

```
select * 
from tablename 
where code in ('aa','bb', ..) 
  and column1 in ('a11','a22',..)
```

There are around 50+ columns where condition needs to apply.

It's taking more than two hours to execute this query. Is there a way to improve this?

[image]

Select query is:

```
SELECT Number, COUNT(Code) AS Volume
FROM TableNameTest 
WHERE LEN(Number) >= 5  
  AND Code IN ( '851','852','853','870','871','872','002','004','006','013','017') 
  AND (ColumnName IN ('N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
       OR ColumnName2 IN ('N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
      OR ColumnName3 IN ('N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
      OR ColumnName4 IN ('N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName5 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName6 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName7 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName8 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName9 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName10 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName11 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName12 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName13 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName14 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName15 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName16 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName17 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName18 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName19 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName20 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName21 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName22 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName23 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName24 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName25 IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 ) AND ( ColumnName NOT IN   (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName2 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName3 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName4 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName5 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName6 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName7 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName8 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName9 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName10 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName11 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName12 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName13 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName14 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName15 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName16 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName17 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName18 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName19 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName20 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName21 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName22 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName23 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName24 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 OR ColumnName25 NOT IN  (
 'N179','R9002','R40.2240','R40.2241','R40.2242','R40.2243','R40.2244','R40.2245','R40.2246','R40.2247','R40.2248','R40.2249','R40.2230','R40.2231','R40.2232','R40.2233','R40.2234','R40.2235','R40.2236','R40.2237','R40.2238','R40.2239','N289','R410','R34','N178','J80')
 ) ) group by  Number Order by  Number
```

`

Comment: please post a schema and an explain of the query.

Comment: Added Execution plan in question

Comment: The query in your execution plan doesn't seem to be the same - it's apparently using an aggregate function. Also, without a schema, we're just guessing - are there any indexes on your table?

Comment: Yes indexing is there for all columns which are in where condition. Do I post Select query or schema of table?

Comment: Normalize your table.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly the absence of an index that matches the where clause. Unless you post your DDL complete with indexes, we can't do more than guess, though.

Comment: Your small example is totally different than the actual query. Criteria with `and` is a totally different than criteria with `or` -- especially the huge `not in` -thing, since no index helps in `not in` cases. The query is too big to spend my time in, but don't you have same values in both `in` and `not in` part? How's that going to really work?

Comment: @dnoeth We all know it's much much more work than simply normalizing one table. Don't think that will be a short term solution, although it needs to be said that the table is not normalized and of course the result is horrible execution plans for queries like these.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to process records where at least one column exists which is in the set and at least one column exists which is not in the set and have one of the codes provided.

I assume that you don't want to evaluate such a query just once, so a restructuring or reindexing of your data would be reasonable.

Normal Indexing will not help, the jumping between indexes and data will make them unusable. Bitmap-Indices would work, since logical operations over many indices are very fast. But only if there are not too many different codes and columnnames-values? But Sql-Server does not provide these.

Probably these column-store-indices would help, sqlserver is providing. I admit, I have no experience with these.

Or you could switch to oracle or postgres. But only after extensive tests!!